# How to structure API code in a Vue Single-Page App?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, single-page-application

I'm building a fairly large SPA using Vue (and Laravel for RESTful API). I'm having a hard time finding resources about this online - what's a good practice to organise the code that communicates with the server?

Currently I have `src/api.js` file, which uses `axios` and defines some base methods as well as specific API endpoints (truncated):

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API_URL;

const get = async (url, params = {}) => (await axios.get(url, { params }));
const post = async (url, data = {}) => (await axios.post(url, data));

export const login = (data) => post('users/login', data);
```

And then in my component, I can do

```
...
<script>
import { login } from '@/api';

...
methods: {
   login() {
       login({username: this.username, password: this.password})
           .then() // set state
           .catch() // show errors
   }
}
</script>
```

Is this a good practice? Should I split up my endpoints into multiple files (e.g. `auth`, `users`, `documents` etc.)? Is there a better design for this sort of thing, especially when it comes to repetition (e.g. error handling, showing loading bars etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question but using `async` functions to `await` a single promise is completely redundant. `const get = (url, params) => axios.get(url, { params })` is much more concise

Comment: @Phil it's a prototype code, I'll make sure to adjust that, cheers!

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Vue, but for a large project, I would suggest taking a look at VuexStore for state managing.
You can use modules with it to separate your endpoints and get a tidy structure for your code. 
Also, you can use axios plugin to run some code on each successful response or error and dotenv package to define your environment variables as API URLs.

That's what makes projects easier for me.

Comment: @Serhiy we will be using Vuex, but with Vuex actions the actual api defining file will be the same, just imported into the actions file, rather than the component file? As in that change doesn't change anything in the actual organisation of the api integration codebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using Vue and expect to be fetching the same data from the same component every time, it's generally [idiomatic](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html) to retrieve the data and assign it using the component's `mounted` lifecycle hook, like so:

```
<template>
<h1 v-if="name">Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://example.com/api')
      .then(res => {
        this.name = res.data.name;
      })
      .catch(err => 
        // handle error
      );
  },
};
</script>
```

If you're going to be using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) as mentioned in one of your comments, you'll want to put your API call into the store's actions property.

You'll end up with a Vuex store that looks [something like this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html):

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    exampleData: {},
  },

  mutations: {
    setExampleData(state, data) {
      state.exampleData = data;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    async getExampleData() {
      commit(
        'setExampleData',
         await axios.get('https://www.example.com/api')
          .then(res => res.data)
          .catch(err => {
            // handle error
          });
      );
    },
  }
});
```

Of course, breaking out your state, actions, and mutations into modules as your app grows is good practice, too!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vue CLI it will setup a basic project structure. With a HelloWorld component. You will want to break your vue app into components. Each component should have a defined role that ideally you could then unit test.

For example lets say you want to show list of products then you should create a product list component.

```
<Products :list="products" />
```

In your app you would do something like

```
data() {
  return {
    prodcuts: []
  }
},
mounted() {
  axios.get('/api/products').then(res => {
    this.products = res.data
  })
}
```

Whenever you see something that "is a block of something" make a component out of it, create props and methods and then on the mounted hook consume the api and populate the component.